# How to extend a view from an external app?

Tags: django, django-views, django-users

I have a django project that uses views from an external app.  The view displays a form but does not save the user. I want to be able to remember this user in order to grant him permission for another view.  How do I extend the external app's view so it saves the user who's filling out this form?

For example:
User A fills out a form to post a job. Users B and C apply to this job. I want to show user A the people who have applied to the job-post (users B and C) but only if user A is indeed the creator of the job post.

I hope I make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally not feasible. You should consider rewriting the view fresh, monkey-patching it into the original app if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Some options that you can consider:

1. Make sure that external app don´t have "Django signals" that you can use.
2. If the "external app" is from your project, you can call a function from another app, like a "manual hook"
3. If isn´t from your project, but its a "class based view", you can inherit and override only the methods you need, and reuse parent method calling "super", if you want.
4. If the external app is not from your project, it´s not recomended modify, then you can do what Ignacio says.
5. It´s inusual but maybe you can call the view since your new rewrited view

I hope this can help you to reuse functionality.